# How can I simplify this generator to eliminate the recursion?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generator

I'm trying to create a generator that yields values between a given range. My requirements are:

- all emitted values are unique
- the order of values is the same every time the generator is run
- each value is far away from previously emitted values
- it is not known how many values will be generated

I've decided to model this as a tree, and doing something like a breadth first search to split the range up into even sized subdivisions, and iterating over each layer in an order that avoids adjacent node visiting.

I've come up with the following solution which works, however I don't like that it is using recursion, and I suspect it can be rewritten to eliminate the recursion (maybe a queue?) A bit stuck here. Here's what I have so far:

```
function* orderedSubdivisor(start: number, end: number): Generator<number> {

    const mid = (end - start) / 2 + start
    
    yield mid

    const left = orderedSubdivisor(start, mid)
    const right = orderedSubdivisor(mid, end)

    while (true) {
      yield left.next().value
      yield right.next().value  
    }
}

const iter = orderedSubdivisor(0, 64)

console.log(Array.from({length: 63}, () => iter.next().value))
```

thanks!

Comment: Clever and concise approach. I think this *is* a great place for recursion - is there a reason you don't want to use it, or just for curiosity on how a similar algorithm might be rewritten?

Comment: Thanks yea curiosity is a part of it, also part of me wonders how well it would scale to longer iterations. For my actual use case (mapping to hues in a colour wheel) it doesn’t matter much as the count will be low, but it is an interesting general problem, and I’d like a more general and robust solution if one exists

Comment: You might want to generate a [random permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation) with a seed value. Or maybe use a [linear congruential generator with maximum period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#c_%E2%89%A0_0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model this using a binary counter to represent the position/path in your tree. The least significant bit decides whether you are in the left or right half of the top branch, the second-least significant bit decides whether you are in the left or right half on the second level, and so on:

```js
function* orderedSubdivisor(start, end) {
    for (let i=1; true; i++) {
        let sum = start;
        let part = end-start;
        for (let j=i; j; j=j>>>1) {
            part /= 2;
            if (j & 1) sum += part;
        }
        yield sum;
    }
}

const iter = orderedSubdivisor(0, 64)

console.log(Array.from({length: 63}, () => iter.next().value))
```

In fact you can see that you've essentially just created a counter, but flip the bit order of every yielded value:

```js
function* orderedSubdivisor(start, end) {
  const mid = (end - start) / 2 + start
  yield mid
  const left = orderedSubdivisor(start, mid)
  const right = orderedSubdivisor(mid, end)
  while (true) {
    yield left.next().value
    yield right.next().value  
  }
}

let i=0;
for (const v of orderedSubdivisor(0, 64)) {
  if (i++ >= 63) break;
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).textContent = v.toString(10).padStart(2)+': 0b'+v.toString(2).padStart(6, '0');
}
```

Comment: oh wow that is a fantastic insight, I should remember to keep half a thought on binary number representations when dealing with trees :) I think given this answers the actual original question this should be the accepted one, but your other answer answers my core question better

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create a generator that yields values between a given range. My requirement [is] to have each value far away from previously emitted values.
> My actual use case is mapping to hues in a colour wheel.

For that, I recommend the [fibonacci hashing technique](https://probablydance.com/2018/06/16/fibonacci-hashing-the-optimization-that-the-world-forgot-or-a-better-alternative-to-integer-modulo/) with the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)/[golden angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_angle), which provides a [very evenly distributed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37498/sequences-of-evenly-distributed-points-in-a-product-of-intervals) output around the colour wheel:

```js
function* orderedSubdivisor(start, end) {
  for (let i=0; true; i+=0.6180339887498951) {
    yield start+(i%1)*(end-start);
  }
}

let i=0;
for (const v of orderedSubdivisor(0, 360)) {
  if (i++ >= 100) break;
  const p = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
  p.textContent = v;
  p.style = `background-color: hsl(${v}deg, 100%, 50%)`;
}
```

Comment: This is a _really_ cool bit of math! I'm unsure if it is actually a better solution though, as visually inspecting the results in the range 0-64 there seems to be far higher number of near values versus my original approach?

Comment: The difference is that your approach has a jump in minimum distance when entering a new level of the tree (i.e. the first 64 values are all evenly spaced with a distance of 1 to their neighbours, while the 65th and the following ones suddenly have a distance of only 0.5 to their neighbours), while the golden angle continuously decreases the distance. So if you know how many values to generate, you get a better yield by spacing them equidistantly; but for an infinite sequence where you don't know how many values you'll need the golden angle is nicer.

Comment: Yea that makes sense, I wonder if there is some kind of threshold where one approach is better than the other. From a quick fiddle it seems like both have a similar behaviour of there being a step change in "current minimum distance between values". I had kinda expected the golden ratio approach to be more continuous, maybe a flaw in my testing.

I'll have a dig, this is more of a fascinating problem than I had anticipated.